# Stop a form from submitting

Tags: javascript

I have a form which is submitted using Ajax.

If a checkbox is checked (receive latest offers and such), I would like to prevent the form from being submitted, if the fields are not filled out.

If the checkbox is not checked, then I don't care if the fields are filled out, and the form can be submitted even if empty.

The problem I'm currently having is, that the form is being submitted even if the checkbox is checked and the fields are empty.

I tried `return false`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault();`. None of them prevent the form from submitting.

`function check()` is attached to the submit button.

Any and all advice is welcome.

If I can provide any additional information, let me know.

Thank you

```
function check (event) {
    if (adverts.checked === true){
    // if the email field is valid, we let the form submit
        if (!fname.validity.valid) {    
        // If it isn't, we display an appropriate error message
            showNameError();
            return false; //event.preventDefault()//etc etc
        }
        if (!email.validity.valid) {
            showEmailError();
            return false; //event.preventDefault()//etc etc
        }
    };
};
```

```
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById("allow").addEventListener("click", sendAjax);
}, 1);
```

```
<button id="allow" onclick="check()">
    <span id="a"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: sendAjax should be called inside check function.

Comment: Try cancelling the onsubmit event of the form instead of the onclick on the button.

Comment: @chandan I'll give it a try.

Comment: @chandan thanks. that solved it. Make this an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chandan suggested, I edited `function check()` and it works.

RollingHogs answer should also work, but the button I'm using is not type submit, as a few other ajax functions need to run before the form is submitted, so I can not accept that.

Anyway, this is the code that does the job:

```
function check (event) {
    if (adverts.checked === true){
    // if the email field is valid, we let the form submit
        if(!fname.validity.valid && !email.validity.valid){
            showNameError();
            showEmailError();
        }else if (!fname.validity.valid) {
        // If it isn't, we display an appropriate error message
            showNameError();
        }else if(!email.validity.valid) {
            showEmailError();
        }else{
            sendAjax();
        }
    }else{
        sendAjax();
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you stop `button.onclick` from propagation, not `form.onsubmit`. Try moving `check()` from onclick to onsubmit:

```
<form id="fname" ... onsubmit="check(event)">
  <button id="allow" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Function `check()` should work without any edits then.

Also, see code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)